# Which MQTT library to use for connecting ESP8266 Wifi-Mdodule on Arduino DUE

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp8266, arduino-due, arduino-esp8266

I have succesfully established a Wifi-Connection with my Arduino DUE and an ESP8266-01 Module attached to it. I now want to establish a connection to an IoT Platform (e.g io.adafruit.com) with a MQTT Protocol. However the MQTT Library provided by the  IoT Platform does not support the Arduino DUE. When searching for a fitting library I always come across libraries that use the ESP8266 module directly without the Arduino DUE. Is there a library that I can use for this special application ?

Comment: Have you gave a try for the answer?

Comment: Sry we did not have the time to check wether it worked or not. We simply used the REST APi and made our own headers that were sendt. I am not quite sure about the PubSubClient; but I think it may only work if you are flashing the ESP directly from the Arduino IDE and not like you are using and Arduino DUE to connect to the ESP - but this is just a guess from a far away project. Sry that I cannot give you an upvote at the moment since I am not able to verify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current libraries fairly requires Ethernet or WiFi client instances to use their protocol implementation and connect to the MQTT. In AT mode, you are posting a raw text data and it is not appropriate to create protocol depended headers etc. I thought that you need another serial firmware to include it and found this :

http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=espduino

As it denotes, required library has a different communication method but no harm, you can still send data to it via AT commands.

Here is another serial arduino library to work with [ESP](https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp/tree/master/). It declares a client called ESPWiFiClient and looks like you need to give it as parameter to the PubSubClient's constructor.

```
WiFiEspClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient );
```

Good luck!